# Selenium with Python: Send keys to an iframe

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I went through a few posts on SO and used the suggested approach of switching to the iframe -

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id(iFrameID))
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('HTML/BODY')
```

However, I get a `NoSuchElementException` for the find by xpath.

I then added a `print (driver.page_source)` after switching to the iframe, and saw the following structure -

```
<HTML dir=ltr><HEAD><LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css 
href="/_layouts/1033/styles/core.css">
<META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 11.00.9600.18639"></HEAD>
<BODY class=ms-formbody contentEditable=true style="BORDER-TOP: medium none; 
BORDER-RIGHT: medium none; BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none; BORDER-LEFT: medium 
none; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white" scroll=yes WebLocale="1033"
BaseElementID="baseTextField" wordWrap="false" RestrictedMode="true">
<DIV></DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

The HTML/BODY structure is definitely present so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in the find_element_by_xpath. I also tried /HTML/BODY and//HTML/BODY with no luck.

As a workaround, I tried to bring the RTE into focus by clicking the iframe and then using ActionChains

```
driver.find_element_by_id(iFrameID).click()
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys("Lorem Ipsum")
actions.perform()
```

But got the following error:

```
NameError: name ActionChains is not defined
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I might be able to help, if you can post your source code :)

Comment: it's obvious that you are missing import, try `from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
`

Comment: Can you actually copy-paste the HTML of the `<iframe>` tag you are trying to switch to? The output of `driver.page_source` has been truncated. Stop relying on that method... it's inconsistent and doesn't do what you think it does. 
@AzatIbrakov he is trying to switch to an `iframe`, he first encountered the lib import as you pointed out. But, he still will get the `NoSuchElementException` error for the `driver.find_element_by_id(iFrameID).click()` command.

Comment: @Sid Can you consider updating the HTML DOM of the iframe you are trying to switch? Do update what is your next step after switching to the iframe. Thanks

Comment: @Sid, why are you trying to click the `iframe` and sent text to `ActionChains()` instance!? Share what exactly you want to do as for now your logic is quite unclear

Comment: Did you already try to add wait to element / sleep after you switched to iframe?

Answer (score 2):

This post is a little old, but I hope my solution is able to help anyone out there that is facing similar issues.

So the way I managed to send keys into an IFrame using Selenium Python is by first using switch_to_frame of iframe after switching to the iframe, we can query the document like new document using driver.find_element

Sample shown below

```
#Select iFrame
element = driver.find_element_by_id(iFrameID)

#Switch to iFrame
driver.switch_to_frame(element)

#Query document for the ID that you're looking for
queryElement = driver.find_element_by_id(queryID)

#Send key to the ID
queryElement.send_keys("L")

#Switch back to default content from iFrame
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```